# Dns using BIND9 and DHCP: no address records

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns, bind

I am using bind9 to configure a simple server, but when I try to execute

named-checkzone mired.org /etc/bind/db.mired.org

I got via console, NS 'asterix.mired.org' has no address records A or AAAA

Here is the db.mired.org conf file:

```
$ORIGIN mired.org.
$TTL 3D
@ IN SOA dns.mired.org. admin.mired.org. ( 1 8H 2H 1W 1D )
                NS              asterix
                MX 10           asterix
adm1            A               192.168.50.201
adm2            A               192.168.50.202
adm3            A               192.168.50.203
adm4            A               192.168.50.204
adm5            A               192.168.50.205
adm6            A               192.168.50.206
adm7            A               192.168.50.207
adm8            A               192.168.50.208
adm9            A               192.168.50.209
adm10cap        A               192.168.50.210
www             CNAME           asterix
bbdd            CNAME           asterix
mail            CNAME           asterix
dns             CNAME           asterix
dns2            CNAME           asterix
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error message says exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @Scott close close close

Answer (score 0):

Answer here,
asterix was needed as a A record.

asterix      A       192.168.100.2